# Transforming NFA into DFA

Tags: formal-languages, automata

In the examples I was given I have the following NFA diagram:
[image]

Then it gives the conversion process[image]

Could someone explain to me the process of obtaining the second column:

{1,2,4} = a{1, 2, 3, 4}, b{1, 4, 5}

Comment: Google "powerset construction".

Comment: @raphael, where is our reference powerset thread?

Comment: @RanG. We don't have one, and I don't think we strictly need to. It's included in any textbook on the matter, and even [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) (if not very nicely). So this would go under "general reference", I think, and I'd assume everybody who faces an exercise problem like to have seen the algorithm in class.

Comment: @Raphael the same holds also to several other questions to which we do have a reference question...

Comment: @RanG. That is certainly true. However, in most cases I have in mind, there are either a) several methods or b) the methods are not algorithmic so a didactic exposition (!= most stuff on Wikipedia) is advantageous. In this case, there is *one* algorithm that is immediate to apply, so a reference question can not do more than state the algorithm and maybe one or two examples. Do you disagree? (Nothing prevents you in principle to creating such a post, mind.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard procedure for converting NFAs to DFAs. The first row should be read as "If you know you're in one of the states $0$, $1$ and $4$ and you read an $a$, you'll have to be in one of the states $1$, $2$ and $4$; if you read a $b$, you'll have to be in one of $1$, $4$ and $5$." The other rows are similar.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, just an additional question how do we get the initial states for the two rows? ie. E(0) = {0, 1, 4}, E(1) = {1, 2, 4}

Comment: $E(0)$ is the start state of the NFA plus all states you can reach from it just using $\epsilon$-transitions. The rest of the state sets in the first column are all of the ones that appear in columns 2 and 3. (You could compute a row for every set of NFA states but it's more efficient to just do the ones that appear in columns 2 and 3.)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

$$\begin{align*}\delta_d(\{1, 2, 4\}, a) &= \delta(1, a) \cup \delta(2, a) \cup \delta(4, a)\\
 &= \{1, 2, 3, 4\}\\[2ex]
\delta_d(\{1, 2, 4\}, b) &= \delta(1, b) \cup \delta(2, b) \cup \delta(4, b)\\
&= \{1, 4, 5\}
\end{align*}$$